# Google Plus "!" account bots

Tags: problem-users, spam

I am a moderator on a Google Plus community and we have accounts that start with an "!" and some nonsense after it. Does anyone know where these come from and how to deal with them (in addition than removing/banning them, which causes other ones to enter)?

Comment: Do these accounts post anything else in addition to the nonsense in the display name?

Comment: Flaggers, I think this question falls into "On Topic", as described [here](http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/128/78). I think it falls into the 3rd bullet: "Questions about user behaviour that might be considered while building such a system ("how can I trick a ban evader; what do they miss that I can use to find them again?") should be on-topic."  If you disagree, please utilize [Meta](http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/) to argue your point and cast a flag to close here (not an "Other..." moderator flag).

Comment: @just_curious A few of them might post a spam or fake advertisement once in a while, but most don't do anything.

Comment: Maybe  an appropriate captcha that can not be solved by bots would do the job?

Comment: @just_curious It is Google Plus, so we have very little power on putting entering restrictions without blocking anyone from entering.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it's about Google Plus which has since closed down.